# What are the restrictions to \newline? #tabularx, #\newline Put differently, why doesnt the first \newline in this example take effect?

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\small\arraybackslash}X}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c | L{1.3} | L{1.2} L{1.2} | L{.65} L{.65} }
    Mechanism\newline\ State
  & Initialization\newline\ feh
  & xAV
  & yAV
  & Hard reset (jumper)
  & Hard reset (swap) \\
  \begin{minipage}[t]{20pt}
    Mechanism\\ State
  \end{minipage}
  & Initialization
  & xAV
  & yAV
  & Hard reset (jumper)
  & Hard reset (swap)
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: paste of output from above code]

Versions:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `z1' with ``xelatex  -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" z1.tex''
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/MacPorts 2017_1) (preloaded format=xelatex)
  restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
...
```

Comment: Because the first item is not in a paragraph, it’s a centered column.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: Ah, ok.  So it has to either be a p{}, m{}, b{} or X (in tabularx) for \newline to take effect.  duh, I should have known!  Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\newline` works only  in paragraph  mode cells, not in the standard `l,c,r`. But for these cells, you have the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks and a common formatting. By default the contents of a `\makecell` or `\thead` command is centred, both horizontally and vertically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\small\arraybackslash}X}%
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c | L{1.3} | L{1.2} L{1.2} | L{.65} L{.65} }
    \thead[tc]{Mechanism\\ State}
  & Initialization\break\ feh
  & xAV
  & yAV
  & Hard reset (jumper)
  & Hard reset (swap) \\
  \makecell{Mechanism\\ State}
  & Initialization
  & xAV
  & yAV
  & Hard reset (jumper)
  & Hard reset (swap)
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `\multicolumn` for a single column to temporarily create a paragraph cell.

Comment: You're right, but as `\makecell` is very useful in some contexts and is shorter to type…  There's also `\Centerstack` from the `stackengine` package.